# CDI - Observing Container Events

Tags: java-ee-6, cdi, jboss-weld

I am trying to observe both the startup and shutdown events for a CDI web application.  I have an ApplicationScoped bean that listens for those events:

```java
@ApplicationScoped
public class PrettyfacesStartupObserver
{
    private static final Log LOGGER = LogFactory.getLog(PrettyfacesStartupObserver.class);

    public PrettyfacesStartupObserver()
    {
        LOGGER.debug("\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\nconstructor");
    }

    public void onStartup(@Observes
    AfterBeanDiscovery afterBeanDiscovery
                                             )
    {
        LOGGER.debug("\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\nafter bean discover");
    }

    public void onStartup(@Observes
    AfterDeploymentValidation afterDeploymentValidation
                                             )
    {
        LOGGER.debug("\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\nafter deployment validation");
    }

    public void onShutdown(@Observes
    BeforeShutdown beforeShutdown
                                                )
    {
        LOGGER.debug("\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\nbefore shutdown:" + beforeShutdown);
    }
```

I don't see anything in the logs.

What am I missing?

Comment: I have an empty beans.xml in this archive.  I don't believe this bean ever gets constructed as I don't see any log statements produced by it.

Comment: is your logger configured properly? Try System.out

Comment: Na, I tried that along with System.exit, both were a no go.  It's never being called.  Here is what I'm trying to run:

http://github.com/walterjwhite/prettyfaces.extension.sitemap
http://github.com/walterjwhite/prettyfaces-tests

mvn clean package embedded-glassfish:run -P Glassfish,development

Comment: Check out the weld and cdi-jee6 branches.  Let me know if that works for you.

Comment: I need to use @Stateless instead of @ApplicationScoped on the class.  Also, my after deployment validation and before shutdown method aren't being called?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Thanks to Pete Muir, the solution was to implement the Extension interface.  Once I did that, along with creating a special file, it worked perfectly.

The thing to remember is, if you want to observe (or act on) container events, you must implement the extension interface as it is a special event.

https://docs.jboss.org/weld/reference/latest/en-US/html/extend.html#d0e4984

Walter

Comment: Thanks for posting this. +1 all around.

Comment: You mention creating a special file. What file was that?

Answer (score 7):

The "special file" mentioned by Walter White is:

`META-INF/services/javax.enterprise.inject.spi.Extension`

That file should contain the fully-qualified name of your Extension class.
ie:

```
org.mydomain.extension.MyExtension
```